# Determine if a resource from the ServletContext is a file or directory

Tags: java, servlets

Given that we use the code below
Set paths = servletCtxt.getResourcePaths("/app/themes");

How can we tell if the path in paths is directory or a actual file?

This would usually be in an zipped war.

What I did find is this, but I am betting it isn't reliable:

When it is a file

```
servletCtxt.getResource(dir).getContent()
    returned (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream) java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@5a645a64
```

When it is a directory it returned:

```
(org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext) org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext@57155715
```

Is it safe to say that I could use a instanceof with InputStream on what is returned by getContent?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without testing I see the following in the JavaDoc of [`getResourcePaths()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourcePaths(java.lang.String)):

> Paths indicating subdirectory paths end with a /.
>
> [...]
>
> For example, for a web application containing:
>
> - `/welcome.html`
> - `/catalog/index.html`
> - `/catalog/products.html`
> - `/catalog/offers/books.html`
> - `/catalog/offers/music.html`
> - `/customer/login.jsp`
> - `/WEB-INF/web.xml`
> - `/WEB-INF/classes/com.example.OrderServlet.class`
> - `/WEB-INF/lib/catalog.jar!/META-INF/resources/catalog/moreOffers/books.html`
>
> `getResourcePaths("/")` would return `{"/welcome.html", "/catalog/", "/customer/", "/WEB-INF/"}, and getResourcePaths("/catalog/")` would return `{"/catalog/index.html", "/catalog/products.html", "/catalog/offers/", "/catalog/moreOffers/"}`.

Seems like you can simply rely on the last character of the path.